# Magento2 Order Summary - unable to process binding

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, knockoutjs

I'm getting issues with the Order Summary on the checkout of my magento2 site.

No products or information about the order is being displayed at all and in console I get a knockoutjs error which I'm struggling to see how it helps.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return maxCartItemsToDisplay < getCartLineItemsCount() }"
>
> Message: maxCartItemsToDisplay is not defined
>       at if (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2624), :3:55)
>       at ko.computed.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:3989)
>       at evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:1737)
>       at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:1946)
>       at init (knockout.js:3988)
>       at knockout.js:2989
>       at Object.ignore (knockout.js:1249)
>       at knockout.js:2988
>       at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.js:151)
>       at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:2974)

Any help with this or how to debug this would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you made any changes to the templates? The majority of cases I've seen this error it has been when someone has removed something in the template, such as the scope attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my project so I'm not entirely sure. By template, are you referring to the html file?

Comment: Yeah, if they're overwriting default templates try and revert them back to default and see if it works. If it does you know the problem is in the template.

Comment: I've got an overwritten cart-items.js in my theme files. I'm going to remove that and see if that helps, as there isn't any .html files there.

Comment: Latest version of the Porto theme 2.6.1 from Smartwave has this issue. Have reported to them to address. Struggling to make this fix work in our install....

Comment: @MagentoMac if they get back to you on this could you post their answer?

Comment: They've replied to say it's a Magento issue, not an issue with their theme, which is wrong.... they reply with that to every support ticket always, and you have to explain to them in depth why it is a theme issue and not Magento core. The issue doesn't occur with the default Magento2 theme, only the Porto theme from Smartwave for me. Developer console references the knockout.js file located in their theme.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Well yeah, I enabled the default theme for that reason but couldn't replicate the issue so that would suggest the error is theme related.

Answer (score 3):

Recently I've updated magento with 2.1.8 version and got the same issue.
**maxCartItemsToDisplay** variable was added in the new version and is used in the next files

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Cart/CheckoutSummaryConfigProvider.php
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/cart-items.js
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/cart-items.html
```

If you rewrite some of these files you can get an error with summary block on checkout. In my case cart-items.js has been rewritten by Smartwave theme, so I just added the changes to it.

I hope this will be useful to you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying - you mention those three files, but what do I need to do to resolve the error?

Comment: Hi, I've just merged functionality from the new cart-tems.js with cart-items.js from theme.

Comment: Latest version of the Porto theme 2.6.1 from Smartwave has this issue. Have reported to them to address. Struggling to make this fix work in our install....